# STL iterators - purpose

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

What is the purpose of STL iterators? Why have programmers created this concept at all?

Comment: Advantages over what?  What's your alternative?

Comment: Advantages over not using that notion.

Comment: You need some notion of iteration for the containers to useful. If you're asking about the advantages of a uniform iteration interface over ad-hoc iteration (i.e. each container defining its own interface), then Mark B has answered that nicely.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Iterators allow you to separate algorithms from the container. As long as you have a start and end iterator, and know the capabilities of the iterator (random access etc) you can do operations on the range specified by the iterators. For example, see `std::for_each`, `std::transform`. This way you can implement just one version of an algorithm rather than needing to write a new one for each container on which you wish it to operate.

Comment: It's possible Narek is only familiar with containers that are simple to iterate over, such as arrays and linked lists. But data structures may require arbitrarily complex logic to iterate over. You could have a P2P system where each time you increment the iterator you're asking the current server where to find the next server and connecting to it, or something crazy along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

Iterators allow you to traverse container members using pointer-like semantics which would otherwise be impractical for containers with non-contiguous storage.

Comment: Not, not all iterators allow pointer-like semantics, only RandomAccessIterators do (the others don't support `+ x`). And RandomAccessIterators do not necessarily come with contiguous storage (`deque`).

Comment: Just because you can't do arbitrary pointer arithmetic doesn't mean an iterator isn't like a pointer, @Matthieu. Single increments are pointer-like, too.

Comment: Yes, and so are single decrements, and not all iterators support it either. My point is than apart from RandomAccessIterators the other kinds only implement a subset of the operations available with a true pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Iterators provide abstraction. It is not important how you traverse along some container for a method that only wants to operate on the contents of it. Of course iterators need to be more versatile then just that. You want to use the fastest operations avaible but still want to write generic code or you would like iterators that support output. This where type traits come in. This (in combiantion with concepts) is used extensively in the `STL`. See the [SGI Documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html) for an overview.

On the other hand: iterators aren't the best solution for all kinds of problems and thus often get generalized to ranges. (See [boost range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) for an example or [this](http://www.boostcon.com/site-media/var/sphene/sphwiki/attachment/2009/05/08/iterators-must-go.pdf) great talk from boostcon.

Comment: I was about to point out that ranges are just as expressive as iterators and usually easier to understand, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @Caspin Yes, unfortunately not too many people know about them.

Answer (score 3):

> What advantages have STL iterators?

- They allow you to abstract *how you iterate values* from *what you do with the iterated values* allowing for generic algorithms to be written.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> cont;
auto position = std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), 1); // forward search
auto position = std::find(cont.rbegin(), cont.rend(), 1); // backward search
```

- They allow for implementing safe dereferencing (an iterator may be set to throw an exception if it doesn't point to a valid value and you dereference it ), or any other safety checks.
- They allow for arbitrary streams to be treated as iterable sequences.

This allows you to iterate I/O streams for example, writing code like this:

```
std::vector<int> cont;
copy( cont.begin(), cont.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ") );
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are in essence improved version of pointers from C. And BTW the two can be mixed since iterators' behavior is similar to that of pointer.

In C++ that would work without problems:

```
char buf1[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<char> buf2;
buf2.resize(sizeof(buf1));
std::copy( buf1, buf1+sizeof(buf1), buf2.begin() );
std::copy( buf2.begin(), buf2.end(), buf1 );
```

Comment: The `[]` operator isn't overloaded for other STL types like `list`, however, so you can't use them at all in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators make your life easier because you don't need to worry about the underlying structure of the containers you are using in order to iterate over them. This allows you to spend more time working on the algorithms involved than specifics of implementation (which can be complex).

Answer (score 1):

It looks so much more grown-up to write

```
vector<myclass>::iterator myClassVectorIterator;
for(myClassVectorIterator = myClassVector.begin(); 
        myClassVectorIterator != myClassVector.end();
        myClassVectorIterator++)
```

rather than

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) { ...
```

Comment: Yes, first case is much longer, than second and that's all :). (for this example)

Comment: Plus you get so many enteratining error messages if you get a myClassVector and a myClassVectorIterator the wrong way round. Then you can play the fun const/forward/random iterator mixing game.

Comment: The second case would be longer if it also used unnecessarily long variable names. But yes, iterators are overkill in some situations.

Comment: I get (and agree with) the sarcasm, but I want to point out the iterator-way should be pre-increment, and for uber-efficiency make an end iterator to compare against instead of calling end() each time. I actually worked somewhere where this was expected of us :|

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for iterators in STL was to allow algorithms to be written independent of the manner in which the data was stored. Of course, the storage does (or at least can) impose some limitations, which lead to various classes of iterators (e.g., RandomAccess vs. Input) but these are (intended to be) as independent as possible of the underlying data structure.

This allows, for example, a `merge` algorithm to take input from a `vector` and a `list`, and write the output to an `ostream_iterator`, without needing to pay any attention to the differences between the sources and/or destination.

Comment: I never thought of the possibility of merging two different containers like that. +1

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question, however...

STL is C++.  Iterators make it easy to traverse lists of things (usually providing some STL magic juju to handle the types of thing).

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages over what?** Is there some alternative you wish to compare iterators to?

C-style integer sequences, such as `for(i=0;i!=N;++i)` assume the cost of random access in the container, specifically, the cost of accessing element `[i]`, is negligible.

Similarly, pointer increment such as `for(p=&arr[0]; p != p+N; ++p` assumes the implementation of the sequence is a contiguous chunk of memory.

Higher level alternatives have been proposed and many implemented. Ranges, Perl-style "foreach" syntax, Lisp-style "apply".